# Google Sheets script to duplicate a set of data in a pivot table at the beginning of the month?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cut-and-paste

I'm looking to create a script or system where data from a pivot table is copied and pasted into a new sheet in the same doc.

Essentially there is sheet 1 with the pivot table in it and sheet 2 with the raw data which is fed in using n external source.

Ideally at the start of each month at say 00:01 am or as early as possible, this script will take the data from the pivot table and copy it into a new sheet in the same document.

I've seen posts like: [Google Sheets script to duplicate a sheet at the beginning of the month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65622876/google-sheets-script-to-duplicate-a-sheet-at-the-beginning-of-the-month) which duplicate the sheet but that would bring with it the pivot functionality and the data would continue to update over time.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the [Cooper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65623220/14265469) and add these three lines at the end of the function:

```
  var range = nsh.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getDisplayValues();
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

And add the trigger from the [ale13's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65627785/14265469).